# How to make the height of ViewPager inside ScrollView to be MATCH_PARENT?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-scrollview

Previously I had a problem showing `Fragment` from `ViewPager` inside a `ScrollView`. The problem was because we need to put the exact height for `ViewPager`. We cannot rely on `WRAP_CONTENT` or `MATCH_PARENT`. I solved it with code from [here](https://github.com/vabhishek/WrapContentViewPagerDemo/blob/master/DynamicViewPager-master/app/src/main/java/com/example/vihaan/dynamicviewpager/CustomPager.java). Now, my problem is if the height of a `Fragment` is not full screen, I cannot slide the `ViewPager` with the empty part of my screen. I only can slide with the visible part of my `Fragment`. The following is the code.

```
public class CustomPager extends ViewPager {

    private View mCurrentView;

    public CustomPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (mCurrentView == null) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            return;
        }
        int height = 0;
        mCurrentView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int h = mCurrentView.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (h > height) height = h;

        //TODO: if (height < empty space height of a screen) height = empty space height of a screen

        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    public void measureCurrentView(View currentView) {
        mCurrentView = currentView;
        requestLayout();
    }

    public int measureFragment(View view) {
        if (view == null)
            return 0;

        view.measure(0, 0);
        return view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <com.example.CustomPager
            android:id="@+id/custom_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: share your XML layout

Comment: If you use a `ScrollView` outside the `ViewPager` to scroll the content of the `ViewPager`, don't do that, move the `ScrollView` into the individual fragments' layout. If you just have a `ScrollView` outside the `ViewPager` for whatever other reasons, set the [fillViewport](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport) attribute to true on the `ScrollView`.

Comment: @NileshRathod done.

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy I've put `android:fillViewport=true` before but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

Try This Solution.

**android:fillViewport="true"**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <chatapp.com.testdemo.CustomPager
        android:id="@+id/custom_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Seriously, I tried to put `android:fillViewport="true"` before, but it's not working. It changes nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**try this it works in my case**
 male your `com.example.CustomPager`

```
 <com.example.CustomPager
        android:id="@+id/custom_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

and in your fragments make `NestedScrollView` as parent layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context="com.example.Fragment">
```

and make your `ScrollView` `android:fillViewport="true"`

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:fillViewport="true"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Comment: it's not working for me. The `Fragment` is shown, but when I slide on the empty part, I cannot slide it.